# Finding the best way to define a function of dot product for a 3D grid

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, multidimensional-array, dot-product

I am trying to build the following function in a three dimensional domain.

[image]

where [image] is a constant vector, [image] is the position vector, [image] is a constant, and [image] is time.

[image] is a vector of size `[1 3]`, [image] is the array of size `[NX*NY*NZ 3]` that represents the points in the three-dimensional domain, [image] is constant, and [image] is array of size `[1 NT]`.

The following is the setup of the problem.

```
dx = 0.1;
dy = 0.5;
dz = 0.1;

[x, y, z] = meshgrid( (1:100)*dx, (1:100)*dy, (1:100)*dz );
X = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];

k = [1 2 3];
c = 0.5;    
t = 0:0.1:1;
```

In fact, the following loop works but it is very slow (~`200` seconds).

```
f = zeros(numel(X)/3, numel(t));
for n = 1:numel(t)
    for i = 1:numel(X)/3
        f(i, n) = tan(dot(k, X(i,:)+c*t(n)));
    end
end
```

I thought about using `arrayfun` and repeating the vector `k` using `repmat` and dot it with `X` in the second dimension but I don't know what I should do for the multiplication of `c` and `t`.

What would be an efficient way of defining the function for all the points and all the times? The output of this function, for example, looks like an array of size `[NX*NY*NZ NT]`.

Answer (score 2):

`bsxfun` approach to speedup `f` calculation  -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@plus,X,permute(c*t,[1 3 2]));
t2 = permute(k(ones(numel(t),1),:),[3 2 1]);
t3 = bsxfun(@times,t1,t2);
f = tan(squeeze(sum(t3,2)));
```

Or a slight variant -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@plus,X,permute(c*t,[1 3 2]));
t3 = bsxfun(@times,t1,k);
f = tan(squeeze(sum(t3,2)));
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Well not much of improvement there. Yours seems slightly better, +1 there for you too! Thanks btw!! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
f = tan(sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(k, [1 3 2]), bsxfun(@plus, permute(X, [1 3 2]), c*t)), 3));
```

Or replace the outer `bsxfun` by matrix multiplication. This seems to be slightly faster:

```
f = tan(reshape(reshape(bsxfun(@plus, permute(X, [1 3 2]), c*t), [], 3) * k(:), [size(X,1) numel(t)]));
```